# Sharepoint SSA Error: "Sorry, something went wrong"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, web-services

Let me preface by stating that I know almost nothing about sharepoint and knew even less a few weeks ago.

I was tasked with repairing a companies' sharepoint search:

Basically, they would use sharepoint as a search engine for locating documents in a file share. Sometime around the end of January, the SSA crawl would just run and run and never complete and after a few weeks they were unable to search for new documents added to the file shares after the crawl took a dump.

Miraculously, I was able to correct the crawling issue by recreating the SSA - I followed a guide [here](http://melcher.it/2012/07/sharepoint-2013-create-a-search-service-application-and-topology-with-powershell/), cleared the index and ran a full crawl and it completed indexing 9,000+ items in less than an hour.

Of course, now the search feature no longer works. If you perform a search from sharepoint it simply states "sorry, something went wrong"

I scoured the ULS logs and found the following entry to correspond with the correlation id:

> SearchServiceApplicationProxy::Execute--Error occured:
>   System.ServiceModel.ServerTooBusyException: The HTTP service located 
>   at http://sp:32843/511a41f41d2a4f2ea6b7af41f876108c/SearchService.svc
>   is unavailable.  This could be because the service is too busy or
>   because no endpoint was found listening  at the specified address.
>   Please ensure that the address is correct and try accessing the
>   service again later. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server
>   returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.      at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()      at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)     -  -- End of inner exception stack trace ---    Server
>   stack trace:       at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException
>   webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
>
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)      at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
>   TimeSpan timeout)      at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)      at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)      at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)      at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)    Exception rethrown  at [0]:       at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)      at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)      at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.ISearchQueryServiceApplication.Execute(QueryProperties
>   properties)      at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.<>c__DisplayClass6.<Execute>b__5(ISearchServiceApplication
>   serviceApplication)      at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.DoSpLoadBalancedUriWsOp[T](WebServiceBackedOperation`1
>   webServiceCall, Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds, Int32
>   wcfTimeoutInMilliseconds, String operationName)

I know there must be a way to correct this but I've spent so much time getting even this far that my brains feel like liquid goo and I'm not sure what the next step would be. If anyone has had any experience and has experienced anything similar can point me in the right direction, I would be immensely grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you reset the index or create a new service application?  If you did in fact create a new service application, you might need to check your service application associations for your web application and make sure your new one is assigned and is set as the default for the web application.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee704550.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

BTW, the error is stating it can't find a service application endpoint, so either that means it didn't get assigned like I said above or maybe that the service application proxy wasn't created correctly.

Comment: Yes I did reset the index and create the new application. I'll check the link and see if I can wrap my head around it.

Comment: You sir are a genius! I simply unassigned and reassigned it and it seems to be working! Thank you x1000000!!!!

Comment: @Steve Lineberry I had to re-create the search service **but delete the old search proxy first** with a new associated search proxy the search worked cheers!